# Javascript Check all the <span> tags IDs on a page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I need to check the span`s text and based on the text replace it with the span class. It uses asp Repeater and creates a table.

```
<span class="label label-default" id="status">
```

<%# Eval("ProjectStatus")%>

and my not working javascript:

```
var status = document.getElementById('status').innerHTML;

          for (var i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
              if (status === "Completed") {
                  status[i].innerHTML = "<span class='label label-success'> + status + </span>";
              }
          }
```

So the compiled code looks like this:

```
<span class="label label-default" id="status">Completed</span>
<span class="label label-default" id="status">Hopper</span>
```

So my goal here is to check which text has that span and replace its class depending on that text. If its Completed set  class='label label-success' and so on. thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstanding something, is it the value of id attribute you want to put in span content ?

Comment: You mention IDs in the title, but your code doesn't mention anything about ID except for `getElementById`. Please [edit] your question and provide what an example input is and what output you expect.

Comment: Sorry for that. EDITED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you just want to change the class of the span from label-default to label-success.  I do not advise you to remove all the spans and re-add new ones in order to achieve this.  You can simply change their class.

```js
// get all spans with class='label-default'
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span.label-default");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  // if span contains the text Completed, replace label-default with label-success in the span's class list
  if (spans[i].innerHTML == "Completed") {
    spans[i].className = spans[i].className.replace(/\blabel-default\b/, "label-success");
  }
}
```

```css
.label-default {
  background-color: grey;
}
.label-success {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class='label-default'>Completed</span>
<span class='label-default'>Failed</span>
<span class='label-default'>Completed</span>
<span class='label-default'>Completed</span>
<span class='label-default'>Starting</span>
<span class='label-default'>Failed</span>
<span class='label-default'>Completed</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with asp.net, but I think you want something more like this:

```
var statusElem = document.getElementById('status');
var statusText = statusElem.innerHTML;

if (statusText === "Completed") {
    statusElem.className = 'label label-success';
}
```

This will change the classname for a SINGLE status element. If you're creating a table with multiple spans, you would want to do something like this:

```
var statusElems = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
for (var i=0;i<statusElems.length;i++) {
    var statusElem = statusElems[i];
    var statusText = statusElem.innerHTML;

    if (statusText === "Completed") {
        statusElem.className = 'label label-success';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique. Try selecting the elements by class name and iterate over these found elements checking if the `innerHTML` is equals to `Completed`.
The code would by something like this:

```
var status = document.getElementsByClassName("label-default");
for (var i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
  if (status[i].innerHTML === "Completed") {
        alert('Completed');
      status[i].innerHTML = "<span class='label label-success'> + status + </span>";
  }
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hzmzzhpk/) is a working fiddle.